# jquery: keep only single selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Description: Somewhere below BODY is a DIV, say `<div id="keepme"></div>`, that should be kept. Everything else should be `remove()`'ed.

How do you do that with jQuery, i.e. keep this element, delete everything else under body.

Comment: I've come up with numerous clumsy solutions that work, but "need" (that is, I would like) an elegant solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the html  of the body

```
$("body").html($("#keepme"));
```

Comment: That's impressively efficient, +1 =)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$temp = $('#keepme').clone();
$('body').empty().append($temp);
```

Comment: Why `.clone()` instead of `.detach()`?

Comment: In all honesty, it's because I forgot about `detach()`. Sigh... =/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body :not(#keepme)').remove()
```

Comment: this `$('body :not(#keepme)').remove();` or this `$('body *').not("#keepme").remove();` would be possible

Comment: Though micha's solution is faster when you really have only an empty div with no event handlers.

Comment: Won't this just attempt to remove `body`?  `$('body :not(#keepme)')` is the same as `$('body)'`.  Both have one element in them for `document.body`.

Comment: No, it's not the same. `$('body :not(#keepme)')` selects all elements below body which do not have the id "keepme".

Comment: The problem is that #keepme is a child of a deleted element

Comment: No, body itself is not selected by `$('body :not(#keepme)')` and not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Detach the `keepme` div and save a reference, then remove everything else in the document and then append the `keepme` div.

```
var keep = $("#keepme").detach();
$(document.body).empty().append(keep);
```

This will properly keep any event handlers and jQuery data associated with the keepme div while cleaning up that info from everything else that is removed.